# Different results running android cts test with adb as root vs not as root

Tags: adb, root-access, android-cts

The cts test testNoDebuggingFeaturesRestriction from com.android.cts.devicepolicy.ManagedProfileTest fails for me when I run adb as root but it passes when I don't. I am not sure I understand which is the correct behaviour. Is it OK that the results are different?
For adb root the test fails with the warning "Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front." Please let me know in case I am not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to run `CTS` on a `user` build without `root` access.

`testNoDebuggingFeaturesRestriction()` is properly failing when `adbd` is running with `root` privileges. Ignore the warning - it has nothing to do with the reason why the test is failing.

Make sure to read [The Compatilbility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't understand what you meant by "testNoDebuggingFeaturesRestriction() is properly failing when adbd is running with root privileges".  Why is it failing? None of the other tests fail when I run adb using root. Thanks.